# AWS EC2 Volume modification missing

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, filesystems

I modified the Volume of an EC2 instance. I raised to volume's size from 20 GiB to 40 GiB.

When I execute **lsblk**, I get:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  40G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  40G  0 part /
```

But when I execute **df -h --total**, I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M  3.1M   97M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1       20G   20G     0 100% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
total            21G   20G  1.7G  93% -
```

Where is the missing 20G ?

Comment: The disk volume is 40GB but the filesystem is still 20GB. You need to resize the filesystem now. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the volume's file system to take advantage of the increased storage capacity.  You can find step by step instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html